# Create a lock/unlock mechanism in async mode for Python

Tags: javascript, python, promise, async-await, python-asyncio

I have this new_lock function in JS, it's useful to avoid callback hell:

```js
function new_lock(){
    var unlock,lock = new Promise((res,rej)=>{ unlock=res; });
    return [lock,unlock];
}

var [lock,unlock] = new_lock();
call_some_func_with_callback(data,function(){
    print(1);
    print(2);
    unlock();
});
await lock;

print(3)
```

And this is my async Python main function to use 'await' keyword inside:

```py
import asyncio as aio

def new_lock():
    ?How to put code here?
    return lock,unlock

async main():
    lock,unlock = new_lock()

    def cb(ackdata):
       print(1)
       print(2)
       unlock()

    # Python web server emits to client side (browser)
    socketio.emit("eventname",data,callback=cb)
    await lock

    print(3)

if __name__=="__main__":
    loop = aio.get_event_loop()
    t = loop.create_task(main())
    loop.run_until_complete(t)
```

How to create the Python equivalent of the 'new_lock' function in JS? Or even that new_lock function necessary in Python?

Comment: "*Or even that new_lock function necessary in Python?*" I'm not really sure the function is needed in JS. See [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784) EDIT: although, I have to admit, it's a very clever implementation. I do like it on a technical level, however promisifying callbacks is superior as you can immediately use the entire promise API including `await`. There are also libraries for promisifying callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use [socket.io's `AsyncClient`](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asyncclient-class) or [`AsyncServer`](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asyncserver-class) class and just [`await sio.emit()`](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#emitting-events)?

Failing that, you're looking for [an `Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) async primitive:

```
import asyncio as aio

async main():
    ev = aio.Event()

    def cb(ackdata):
       print(1)
       print(2)
       ev.set()

    await socketio.emit("eventname",data,callback=cb)
    await ev.wait()
    print(3)
```

Comment: my client side is not python, it's javascript in browser and the js lib is from https://socket.io

Comment: I understand, but your question is about async Python code that uses the Socket.io library, and you're attempting to do what Socket.io does already with the async client.

Comment: tks, that aio.Event() is simple enough, lock=ev.wait(), and unlock=ev.set

Comment: Will `asyncio.Event` work in the OP's code? The socketio client examples usually end with `sio.wait()` which looks like it has its own event loop.

Comment: i added 'await' before socketio.emit and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You don't show how you set up and run the `socketio` library. If socketio runs inside asyncio (i.e. it invokes the callback from the event loop thread), then your "lock" translates to an asyncio `Future` used in much the same way as a JavaScript `Promise`:

```
def new_lock():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    fut = loop.create_future()
    def unlock():
        fut.set_result(None)
    return fut, unlock
```

If socketio doesn't run inside asyncio, i.e. if it runs in a separate thread from which it will invoke the callback passed to `emit`, then the above is not enough. In that case you need to use thread-aware calls to wake up the event loop and tell it to set the result of the future:

```
def new_lock():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    fut = loop.create_future()
    def unlock():
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(fut.set_result, None)
    return fut, unlock
```

Answer (score 0):

My new_lock function for Python using asyncio module

```py
import asyncio as aio

def new_lock():
    event = aio.Event()
    return event.wait(),event.set

async def main():
   lock,unlock = new_lock()
   ...
   await lock
   ...
```